# Delete command not firing on post back, asp.net repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that contains a data repeater which in turn contains a button that is meant to delete a delete a record from an SQL database. When this button is clicked I receive the following error: Procedure or function 'usp_setKS3_DeleteAssessment' expects parameter '@intAssessmentId', which was not supplied.

If I comment out the KS3_DataSource_Assessment.Delete(); line in the code behind the page loads without error and displays the message, but does not delete the record (which I expect as the line was commented out). I have no idea what to do to make this work... any ideas?

ASP.net

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="KS3_DataSource_Assessment" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sqlWriter %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="usp_getKS3_ManageAssessments" OnSelected="KS3_DataSource_Assessment_Selected" DeleteCommand="usp_setKS3_DeleteAssessment">
                                    <SelectParameters>
                                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="KS3_DropDown_ACYear" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="intACYearId" Type="Int32" />
                                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="KS3_DropDown_Subject" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="intSubjectId" Type="Int32" />
                                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="KS3_DropDown_Year" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="intYearGroup" Type="Int32" />
                                    </SelectParameters>
                                    <DeleteParameters>
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="intAssessmentId" Type="Int32" />
                                    </DeleteParameters>
                                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="KS3_Repeater_Assessments" EnableViewState="true" DataSourceID="KS3_DataSource_Assessment" OnItemDataBound="KS3_Repeater_Assessments_ItemDataBound">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <!-- Assessments -->
                                        <asp:Table runat="server" ID="KS3_Table_Assessments" CssClass="width100pc">
                                            <asp:TableRow CssClass="SectionSubHeader">
                                                <asp:TableCell><%# Eval("txtAssessmentTitle").ToString() %></asp:TableCell>
                                                <asp:TableCell CssClass="width25px alignCenter alignVerticalMiddle" RowSpan="2"><asp:ImageButton SkinID="imgButtonDelete" runat="server" ID="KS3_Button_DeleteAssessment" OnCommand="KS3_Button_DeleteAssessment_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("intAssessmentID").ToString() %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this assessment?\n\nOnce deleted all data is lost.');" /></asp:TableCell>
                                                <asp:TableCell CssClass="width25px alignCenter alignVerticalMiddle" RowSpan="2">Up</asp:TableCell>
                                                <asp:TableCell CssClass="width25px alignCenter alignVerticalMiddle" RowSpan="2">Down</asp:TableCell>
                                            </asp:TableRow>
                                            <asp:TableRow CssClass="BackgroundBlack fontStyleItalic">
                                                <asp:TableCell><%# Eval("txtAssessmentDescription").ToString() %></asp:TableCell>
                                            </asp:TableRow>
                                        </asp:Table>

                                        <!-- Columns -->
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="KS3_DataSource_Columns" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sqlWriter %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="usp_getKS3_ManageAssessments">
                                            <SelectParameters>
                                                <asp:Parameter Name="intACYearId" Type="Int32" />
                                            </SelectParameters>
                                        </asp:SqlDataSource>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void KS3_Button_SelectSubject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (KS3_DropDown_Subject.SelectedIndex == 0) { DisplayMessage("Validation Error", "Please select a subject from the list below.", "error"); KS3_Panel_DataToManage.Visible = false; }
    else if (KS3_DropDown_Year.SelectedIndex == 0) { DisplayMessage("Validation Error", "Please select a year group from the list below.", "error"); KS3_Panel_DataToManage.Visible = false; }
    else
    {
        //No errors detected, start data display
        Master.systemMessageHide();
        KS3_Panel_DataToManage.Visible = true;

        //Update display
        KS3_Label_Title.Text = KS3_DropDown_Subject.SelectedItem.Text.Trim() + " - " + KS3_DropDown_Year.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();

        //Bind the new data to the repeater
        KS3_Repeater_Assessments.DataBind();
    }
}

public void DisplayMessage(string title, string message, string type)
{
    Master.systemMessageShow(title, message, type);
}

protected void KS3_DataSource_Assessment_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AffectedRows < 1) { KS3_Panel_NoAssessments.Visible = true; }
    else { KS3_Panel_NoAssessments.Visible = false; }
}


protected void KS3_Button_DeleteAssessment_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    KS3_Label_Title.Text = "DataSubmitted";
    KS3_DataSource_Assessment.DeleteParameters["intAssessmentId"].DefaultValue = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    Trace.Write("Item Value: " + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    KS3_DataSource_Assessment.Delete();
    KS3_Repeater_Assessments.DataBind();
    DisplayMessage("Assessment Delete", "The selected assessment has been deleted and all associated data has been removed.", "success");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that you are missing this attribute of the data source control:

```
DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure"
```

Default value is Text, which makes control think that the command provided is an SQL statement. Since you are using stored procedure, this is not the behavior you want.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem, I have been stumped for a while and the best of it is I've set  that for the SelectCommandType

Comment: @MarkCrompton Glad it helped. That was an honest miss, but now we have a useful question here on SO, because I'd guess not specifying the command type can be a pretty common issue

Comment: @Andrei if you think it's a good addition to SO questions, you can just upvote it.